# Adding filters to column headers of a grid in extjs4.2

Tags: extjs

I want to filter the records in my grid for which I need textfields on each column header and filter out the records based on what is typed in the textfields. I have tried using Ext.ux.grid.GridHeaderFilters (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?41658-Grid-header-filters ).But this gives me an error: gv.updateHeaders is undefined. I use MVC and here is the code for the grid:

```
   Ext.define(‘MyApp.MyGrid’{
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel', 
   requires :[‘ Ext.ux.grid.GridHeaderFilters’],
  initComponent:function(){
  this.plugins = [‘Ext.create(‘Ext.ux.grid.GridHeaderFilters’)],
  this.columns: [
    { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' ,filter:{xtype:’textfield’}},
    { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', filter:{xtype:’textfield’}}

  ],

   });
```

Have  I missed out anything?
I also thought of using Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature which is present in Sencha Docs but could not use it since it is not present in extjs 4.2.2 lib.

Answer (score -1):

See if this plugin is what you want: [Ext Grid MultiSearch Plugin](http://extjs.eu/software/ext-grid-multisearch-plugin/)